# AS/400 Call PCML File From Java

Tags: java, ibm-midrange, rpgle

I've been using `ProgramCallDocument` on eclipse as below, and it's working fine.

```
pcml = new ProgramCallDocument(as400, "pcml.file.getkursjav");
```

But, I want to call the PCML file using filepath like `D:\xxx\xxx\`, because the PCML file is in another directory. So, how can i using filepath to call the PCML file ?

PS : Currently, the PCML file is under the same java package.

Comment: Have you tried just using the full path name of the file?

Comment: yes, i've been try using full path, but the result is, the file was not found.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to escape the backslashes with another backslash.

pcml = new ProgramCallDocument(as400, "D:\xxx\xxx\");

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this myself, but you might be able to load the PCML document from an input stream.

[ProgramCallDocument(AS400 sys, String docName, InputStream docStream, ClassLoader loader, InputStream xsdStream, int type)](https://javadoc.midrange.com/jtopen/com/ibm/as400/data/ProgramCallDocument.html#ProgramCallDocument(com.ibm.as400.access.AS400,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.InputStream,%20java.lang.ClassLoader,%20java.io.InputStream,%20int))